# Regular expression for String.replaceAll

Tags: java, regex, string, replaceall

I need a regular expression that can be used with `replaceAll` method of String class to replace all instance of `*` with `.*` except for one that has trailing `\`

i.e. conversion would be

```
[any character]*[any character] => [any character].*[any character]
* => .*
\* => \* (i.e. no conversion.)
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use lookbehind.

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("(?<!\\\\)\\*", ".*");
```

**Explanation :**

```
"(?<!" +     // Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below with the match ending at this position (negative lookbehind)
   "\\\\" +       // Match the character “\” literally
")" +
"\\*"         // Match the character “*” literally
```

Answer (score 1):

it may be possible to do without capture groups, but this should work:

```
myString.replaceAll("\\*([^\\\\]|$)", "*.$1");
```